# React tailwind product details dynamic page

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css

I have a react tailwind app which I need to add a feature which displays a dynamic page for each product.

I have products displayed in cards, I want each card to be triggered to display a more details page which should display details of the specific product.

I tried using modals which is kind of a limitation in my case.
I appreciate all the help and guidance I can get, Thank You.

Comment: is this next.js 13 with app router?

Comment: No its reactjs using functional components .@Yilmaz

Answer (score 0):

you get a component like this passing all the products and map it

```
export default function ProductList({ products }: ProductListProps) {
  return (
    <section className="grid md:grid-cols-1 lg:grid-cols-3 gap-4 mt-5 sm:mt-0">
      {products.map((product) => (
        <ProductCard key={product.id} product={product} />
      ))}
    </section>
  );
}
```

then you have a Product card component which I wrapped with `Link` component. when it is clicked, it will be redirected to dynamic page. I added `product.slug` something that unique to the URL.

```
export default function ProductCard({ product }: ProductCardProps) {
  return (
    <Link
      href={`/product/${product.slug}`}
      className="cursor-pointer z-10"
    >
      {/* CARD JSX HERE */}
    </Link>
  );
}
```

now in dynamic page, since you are using react, in `useEffect`, you have to read the `slug` of the url, and then fetch the database with this slug to get the product with this slug. Once you get the correct product, you set the state with `useState` hook, and render the component with this state data. `useEffect` runs before your component is mounted, in other words, it runs before the component is constructed. So before your component is constructed, you prepare the data for the component and then react will render this component with the data